# Jena Thrift serialization OOM due to GC overhead

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jena, thrift

in my program I use a lot of serialization and deserialization of Jena (2.13.0) DatasetGraphs through Thrift and RDFDataMgr but at a certain point I get a OutOfMemory exception. Could someone help me in finding the problem?

```
OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.<init>(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.TRDF.protocol(TRDF.java:72)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.StreamRDF2Thrift.<init>(StreamRDF2Thrift.java:55)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.BinRDF.streamToOutputStream(BinRDF.java:103)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.WriterDatasetThrift.write(WriterDatasetThrift.java:53)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write$(RDFDataMgr.java:1331)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1205)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1195)
```

and

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TCompactProtocol.readFieldBegin(TCompactProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion$TUnionStandardScheme.read(TUnion.java:222)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion$TUnionStandardScheme.read(TUnion.java:213)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion.read(TUnion.java:138)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.wire.RDF_Quad$RDF_QuadStandardScheme.read(RDF_Quad.java:582)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.wire.RDF_Quad$RDF_QuadStandardScheme.read(RDF_Quad.java:549)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.wire.RDF_Quad.read(RDF_Quad.java:464)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.wire.RDF_StreamRow.standardSchemeReadValue(RDF_StreamRow.java:203)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion$TUnionStandardScheme.read(TUnion.java:224)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion$TUnionStandardScheme.read(TUnion.java:213)
    at org.apache.thrift.TUnion.read(TUnion.java:138)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.BinRDF.apply(BinRDF.java:187)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.BinRDF.applyVisitor(BinRDF.java:176)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.BinRDF.protocolToStream(BinRDF.java:164)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.thrift.BinRDF.inputStreamToStream(BinRDF.java:149)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRDFThrift.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:221)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:906)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:577)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:554)
```

Comment: Did you check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839359/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded  and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Yes, I augmented -Xmx from 6 to 10 and added GC options to VM but the problem is still there. With less serialization, with the same amount of data everything worked

Comment: How large are the RDF structures you are reading and serializing? Which collector are you using?

Comment: Without seeing a minimal example of your actual code that exhibits the problem it is impossible for anyone to give a real answer.  All you can possibly get with your question as it stands is pointers to tuning JVM parameters (as you already got) and you already state doesn't really help in your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I'm using Spark and Flink to run complex mapreduce jobs and I serialize a lot of groups of quads using Thrift serialization of DatasetGraph. The methods I use the most are:

```
public static void ser(DatasetGraph dsg, byte[] b, Lang l) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
    RDFDataMgr.read(dsg, is, l);
    closeStream(is);
    dsg.close();
}
```

and

```
public static DatasetGraph deser(byte[] b, Lang l) {
    DatasetGraph ret = DatasetGraphFactory.createMem();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
    RDFDataMgr.read(ret, is, l);
    closeStream(is);
    return ret;
}
```