# Eclipse collapses whenever I generate my apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I've designed an app (chat app) and it all worked fine I left the project and came a month later and tried to generate an apk but eclipse collapsed and said:
gc overhead limit exceeded

I've tried to rewrite everything but I reached a point I faced the same error

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Probably, something is bad in your code, because that error is for running out of memory like in this post: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839359/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

And you can try to use Android Studio, migrating the App is a very simple process: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html