# javax.servlet.ServletException: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I tried create big report. I use JavaEE+JSF+Oragle DB. But my select returm me very very very BIG data. And my server crash with error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: GC overhead limit exceeded
root cause

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
```

I not understand how resolve it problem. Pagination in dataTable work normaly but error show in server side

Comment: How 'big' is the data you are returning from your query? How many concurrent users are requesting this? Do you produce a report of serveral 100 MB's? Can you share you're query and code? Read this, it's essentially the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839359/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

That error basically means that the JVM is spending too much time doing GC and not able to reclaim significant amount of heap. It is quite possible that your application might be leaking memory somewhere. A possible way to diagnose it further would be to take heap dump and analyse it using tools like [MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/) to understand what objects are consuming the memory and where. Based on that you can tune your code further.