# Android studio upgrade gradle error

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using google service gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
=> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); // return bitmap
```

when i upgrade it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
=> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); // return null ??!!
```

Why was that happen ? and what is the solution ?

Comment: Don't know.Probably have bug .what about `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'` ?

Comment: try this `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0`

Comment: When i use  com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 i have this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400059/android-studio-gradle-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception

Answer (score 0):

```
i am using same gradle
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
i am sure issue is with your file path
check below code for testing put an image test.jpg in your DCIM folder and run this code
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            String imageInSD = "/sdcard/DCIM/test.jpg";            
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
            if(bitmap == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you but, when i upgrade  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'  into 8.4.0 i have this problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400059/android-studio-gradle-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception