# Android Studio Build signed App Error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to create signed APK from My Android Studio I get this error:

```
:app:dexRelease
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded","sources":[{}]}
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/33854389/3678308

Answer (score 4):

With the limited information you have provided what I can assume is that you area facing OOM exception when building. you can use

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

in your app gradle file. This should be inside your android {//blah blah }

Give this a shot.
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in your  Application

```
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    //for multiDex  64k
    MultiDex.install(this);
}


add proguard

#suppresses "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class" warning
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

if has , and you need

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```