# G1GC long pause with initial-mark

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, g1gc

With j7u5, G1GC

`"-Xms3200m -Xmx3200m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=14 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=40 -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"`

for a given performance test, my application hits a long pause after 5-hour run predictably. Except this big one (and only), there are small initial-mark phases.

Any suggestions to figure out what is happening to this long pause and how to tune it to avoid such a ***long pause which affects the latency targets (percentiles 98%, 99.999%)?***

```
2012-12-22T09:48:57.966+0000: [GC pause (young) 2436M->1460M(3200M), 0.0627090 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:07.295+0000: [GC pause (young) 2458M->1481M(3200M), 0.0871760 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:18.905+0000: [GC pause (young) 2479M->1503M(3200M), 0.0930280 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:32.366+0000: [GC pause (young) 2501M->1524M(3200M), 0.0827900 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:44.576+0000: [GC pause (young) (initial-mark) 2522M->1546M(3200M), 3.4979530 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.074+0000: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.079+0000: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0056590]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.080+0000: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.173+0000: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 0.0932560 sec]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.180+0000: [GC remark, 0.0470160 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.232+0000: [GC cleanup 1585M->944M(3200M), 0.0180490 secs]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.251+0000: [GC concurrent-cleanup-start]
2012-12-22T09:49:48.255+0000: [GC concurrent-cleanup-end, 0.0047270]
```

Comment: Use default values of parameters for most of them except pause time goal, parallel gc threads etc. G1gc performs better with default values as explained in above first.

Answer (score 2):

for logging, use `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime` for better understanding of the problem and bottlenecks

Its recommended to use `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseCompressedOops` options with G1GC *(if these are supported by native machine/server & JDK version)*

Also please use `-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=VALUE` with the combination of `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=VALUE`  *(It'll control your pauses, better to get combination of best fit values of both params by doing some R&D)* ***BTW we are successfully using combination of values as -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=8000***

The default value of `-XX:NewRatio` param is 40, so its better to have it either 40 or more than 40 e.g. `-XX:NewRatio=50`

Comment: for optimal VM settings see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254041/java-g1-garbage-collection-in-production/14983318#14983318

Answer (score 0):

The G1 GC is an adaptive garbage collector with defaults that enable it to work efficiently without modification. Refer to below question for more details.

[Java 7 (JDK 7) garbage collection and documentation on G1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111310/java-7-jdk-7-garbage-collection-and-documentation/34254605?s=7|0.0000#34254605)

**If you follow above recommendations recommended by oracle:**

1. Remove below parameters

   ```
   -XX:SurvivorRatio=10
   ```
2. `MaxGCPauseMillis=40` is too much aggressive compared to `default value of 200 ms`. Have a reasonable pause time goal.
3. Change  -`XX:ParallelGCThreads=14 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4` as per recommendation depending on number of CPU cores in your server.