# How do you determine the CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction for large Java applications?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

We are using a database (Apache Geode) that is written in Java.  Our servers have 64g of RAM, so we set our Java heap (Xms and Xmx) at about 62g of RAM.

Most Java recommendations I've seen for situations like these is to use the CMS garbage collector, and to set the CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction at somewhere around 68% (give or take a little, but not much).

But my question is:  Why can't we set garbage collection to start at 95% instead of 68%?  It seems maybe wasteful to run Java in such a fashion that you can never use more than 68% of your heap without causing non-stop Garbage Collections.

It's bugging us because we are at a stage where our database is doing non-stop garbage collections, and it's hard to justify more RAM when really the JVM has like 18 gigs free.  :)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: What version of the JVM are you running, and what are your command line args? Have you considered (/ are you able to) benchmarking your deployment using G1 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html). An example configuration is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983318/11173046

Comment: The point of the CMS, i.e. “*Concurrent* Mark Sweep”, is, that the garbage collection can run *concurrently* to your application. But when your application continues, it could be disastrous if only 5% heap memory are left. Hence, the CMS should start much earlier than that. Delaying the GC as long as possible, is a reasonable strategy for a throughput optimized GC, but then, CMS might not be the right GC algorithm for you. Generally, if you don’t know, how to determine a good value for an option, don’t specify that option. The JVM developers did already think hard about reasonable defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answers in the comments, plus some things I've managed to figure out, pretty much answers my question.

It seems one of the concerns is fragmentation.  You can have 20% of your heap free (80% used), and yet your heap can be badly fragmented to where it's difficult to find the large contiguous blocks necessary for operation.  If you start running GC's earlier, like at 70%, you keep fragmentation a little more under control by reclaiming unused objects and creating bigger holes for new objects.

For a non-compacting GC like CMS, there's no 100% guarantee that you'll never become too fragmented to allocate a block of memory, but if you collect early and often you can make that happen as infrequently as possible.