# Is there reason to have more than one executor on one machine/worker node for one spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We know that the parallelism in spark is due to memory partitions, cores/slots/threads and resulting tasks. So when designing a spark submit, is there a need to have more than one executor per worker node for one spark-submit/spark app? I think the executor is mainly to establish parallelism across the worker nodes rather than on the same one. Like a container  of parallel processes on each worker and achieving distributed parallelism by having multiple such containers across the worker-nodes/spark cluster.

Comment: Each worker / executor is given separate numOfCores and memorySize. If your single machine has more cores and memory then you can have multiple executors on the same machine. Ideally you should have num of partitions to be 2-4x times number of executors across whole of your cluster. Each workload is different depending on whether the task is CPU bound or Memory bound.

Comment: Question is not about can or cannot but rationale behind choosing one ore more. I see there is no reason for having multiple executors on one single machine. Be it memory or cpu bound task having one executor on one node/machine does not make difference, why do you think it makes difference if there are multiple executors on the same node, how does it make difference be it memory or cpu intensive task?
On the other One executor on one node has less overhead as it removes slower jvm to jvm communication. Databricks also spawn one executor per node.

Comment: I generally check on Yarn UI if all my cores and memory is being used. Not sure the difference between more cores per worker is better vs more worker with less cores each. Maybe it has to do with fault tolerance. If you have just 1 worker per machine, it means only 1 jvm which if it fails means the whole partition will have to reprocessed

Answer (score 0):

Having a single executor per node has a lot of upsides - the configuration is relatively simple, no need for Spark to distribute broadcast variables more than once per node, processing threads share the same JVM heap that is garbage collected by all threads available on the node. The latter though, having a single JVM heap, can be both an upside or a downside depending on the circumstance: a large JVM heap may perform either better or worse that multiple smaller JVM heaps. Please see resource below for more information.

- [Question of the month: Can heap be too big?](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm045.shtml), Java Performance Tuning.
- [Java very large heap sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214362/java-very-large-heap-sizes), StackOverflow.
- [Few Big Fat JVMs vs. Lots of Small JVMs](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/few-big-fat-jvms-vs-lots-of-small-jvms-1510), Oracle Forums.
- [A Heap of Trouble: Managing Elasticsearch's Managed Heap](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble), ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

An Executor is a single JVM process which is launched for a Spark App on a Worker Node by the relevant Resource Mgr or protocol. Every Spark App acquires its own **set** of Executors via Resource Mgr. An Executor stays up for the duration of the Spark App unless Dynamic Resource Allocation applies.

> **Nowhere** does Spark documentation state that a given Worker Node **cannot** have many Executors for the same Spark App. In a busy Cluster you would likely get this situation if you want Spark Apps to
> start execution, provided there are enough resources available.
>
> That said, Data Bricks on AZURE Cloud, and AWS I presume - will have 1
> Executor for per Worker / Compute Node. Fat Executors as we say,
> considered an issue in plain vanilla Spark, but Databricks does their
> own engineering, so not an issue it would appear now.

With Spark Standalone you will get 1 Executor per Worker unless you play with `spark.executor.cores` and a Worker has enough cores to hold more than 1  Executor.

https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/part-3-efficient-executor-configuration-for-apache-spark-b4602929262 is a good source. The cloud and Databricks have changed things slightly.

So, yes there is, but you do not get to explicitly control that in general.